# Trouble on parsing JSON data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parsing, ruby-on-rails-3

What is wrong in parsing following JSON data

```
'{
   {"errors":
     {"firstname":"is too short"}
   },
   {"account":
     {"firstname":"Test"}
   }
}'
```

for which a get this error?

```
JSON::ParserError in AccountsController#home
706: unexpected token at ... # the code above
```

**?**

In the AccountsController I have

```
JSON.parse(json_data)["errors"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing property names:

```
'{"property1":
   {"errors":
     {"firstname":"is too short"}
   },
  "property2":
   {"account":
     {"firstname":"Test"}
   }
}'
```

Or, you really wanted an array:

```
'[
   {"errors":
     {"firstname":"is too short"}
   },
   {"account":
     {"firstname":"Test"}
   }
]'
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not encapsulate the attribute errors and account. It should probably look like this:

```
'{
  "errors":{"firstname":"is too short"},
  "account":{"firstname":"Test"}
}'
```

Comment: This is the best scenario given the data.

Answer (score 1):

Your data struct appears to be a JSON object {} but you have an array []. The first set of {} should be [].

http://www.jsonlint.com/